# how do you run two do while independently in C

Tags: timer, while-loop, do-while, arrow-keys

im trying to create something similar to "lost in migration" as a project for my finals but im having trouble with the randomization and the timer

how do i run two do while independently of each other

timer should not disappear, and must keep running until time is up, must run independently

randomization must not affect timer

bugs
imputing directional key does not display result

while (timer) once and go to the do while (randomization) and will keep looping at "randomize" and will not go back to the while (timer)

while (timer) is affected bu getch() and getche() pausing it

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<windows.h>
 #include<time.h>

//******************************************//
//       DEFAULT BUILT-IN CLOCK             //
//******************************************//

void Wait(int seconds)
{
   clock_t end wait;
   endwait = clock () + seconds * CLK_TCK;
   while (clock() < end wait) {}
}

//***********************************************************//
//                    DIRECTIONAL KEYS                       //
//***********************************************************//

#define LEFT 75
#define RIGHT 77
#define UP 72
#define DOWN 80

int rdtsc()
{
as m volatile("rdtsc");
}

int main()
{
    char ans;
    int image;
    int loop=1;    
    int correct=0, total=0;
    int sec=0, min=0;

//***********************************************************//
//                       TIMER                               //
//***********************************************************//
int x=1;
while(1==1)
{
    Wait(1);
    sec++;
    if(sec==46)
    {
           loop=0;
    }

    printf("%i:%i\n\n", min, sec);

//***********************************************************//
//                RANDOMIZED IMAGES                          //
//***********************************************************//


fflush(st din);
srand(rdtsc());
image=rand()%4;

do
{

    if(image==0)
    {
    printf(">>IMAGE 1 CORRECT LEFT<<");    
    ans=getche();                    
                    if(ans==LEFT)
                    {        
                    printf("\n\ncorrect!");           
                    }
                    else
                    if(ans!=LEFT)
                    {
                    printf("\n\nwrong!");
                    }   
    }
    else
    if(image==1)
    {
    printf(">>IMAGE 2 CORRECT UP<<");
    ans=getche();
                    if(ans==UP)
                    {         
                    printf("\n\ncorrect!");           
                    }
                    else
                    if(ans!=UP)
                    {
                    printf("\n\nwrong!");
                    }   
    }
    else
    if(image==2)
    {
    printf(">>IMAGE 3 CORRECT DOWN<<");
    ans=getche();
                    if(ans==DOWN)
                    {
                    printf("\n\ncorrect!");                     
                    }
                    else
                    if(ans!=DOWN)
                    {
                    printf("\n\nwrong!");
                    }        
    }
    else
    if(image==3)
    {
    printf(">>IMAGE 4 CORRECT RIGHT<<");
    ans=getche();
                    if(ans==RIGHT)
                    {      
                    printf("\n\ncorrect!");           
                    }
                    else
                    if(ans!=RIGHT)
                    {
                    printf("\n\nwrong!");
                    }           
    }    
getch();
system("cls");
}
while(loop==1);

}

getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a state machine for each of the two tasks you're trying to accomplish.
- Write the code to implement each state machine using a switch statement.
- Place them sequentially within an outer loop.

  for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
  {

  switch ( state1 )
    {
       case 0:
         // do whatever you need for task 1
    }

  switch ( state2 )
    {
       case 0:
         // do whatever you need for task 2
    }

  }